# Java Android SQLite String not equal to what it's supposed to be

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a class named "note" which provides a note with a title, a note, and a color.
I save all the notes in a SQLite database. BDDManager is my SQLite database manager it inserts, removes etc... notes from database.

```
    private void readNotes(){
    Note note = new Note();

    BDDManager.open();

    note = BDDManager.getNoteWithTitle("Title");

    if(note != null && note.getTitle() == "Title"){

        addCardNote(note);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, note.getCouleur(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

    }

    BDDManager.close();
}
```

In this part of the code, if I don't remove "note.getTitle()=="Title"" it doesn't work. And all the strings from my database are not equal to what they are supposed to be equal

Comment: Compare strings with `String`'s `equals` method, not with `==`.

Comment: Ok this problem is solved, thanks rgettman

Comment: My true problem is this one: I get the color of the note and then send it to a class wich is supposed to create a note with the color given, but it doesn't work

Comment: `==` compare the reference for the `String` Object if they are referenced to the same Object then returned `true` regarding of what is the value for each one, but when you use `equal()` method the value will be compared, **NOT** the reference for `String` Object !!

Comment: Ok thanks everyone, I will use equal() to set the color, I was using == for it, thanks !
Problem solved !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
if(note != null && note.getTitle() == "Title"){
```

You should try

```
if(note != null && note.getTitle().equals("Title")){
```